# Parse JSON Object within Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I am using nodejs script to parse one of the json string but not able to figure out how to parse data from onject within object.

Here is JSON Object:

```
{
    "Item":{
        "job_change_request":"task0020764",
        "id":"a156fc4e-e8d4-424f-a792-0c8cf8e3ca46",
        "job_data":{
            "location":"sdqa03",
            "id":"8f6087cb-b33d-41c4-9a71-e865fd444a1d",
            "customer_id":"cust01291",
            "change_request":"task0020764"},

"job_requested_time":"2019-08-09T20:54:20.237536",
            "job_type":"create_subnet",
            "job_status":"completed"},
            "ResponseMetadata":{

"RequestId":"3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
                "HTTPStatusCode":200,
                "HTTPHeaders":{
                    "server":"Server",
                    "date":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 20:57:23 GMT",
                    "content-type":"application/x-amz-json-1.0",
                    "content-length":"385",
                    "connection":"keep-alive",
                    "x-amzn-requestid":"3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
                    "x-amz-crc32":"1811639896"},
                    "RetryAttempts":0
            }
}
```

I need to access job_type, job_status and id within job_data.

Anyone can please help me here.

Comment: Your "json object" doesn't have another "json object" inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? You just want to read the values of those three fields?

Using [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = {  statuscode: 200,  statustext: "OK",  responseBody: {    Item: {      job_change_request: "task0020764",      id: "a156fc4e-e8d4-424f-a792-0c8cf8e3ca46",      job_data: {        location: "sdqa03",        id: "8f6087cb-b33d-41c4-9a71-e865fd444a1d",        customer_id: "cust01291",        change_request: "task0020764"      },      job_requested_time: "2019-08-09T20:54:20.237536",      job_type: "create_subnet",      job_status: "completed"    },    ResponseMetadata: {      RequestId: "3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",      HTTPStatusCode: 200,      HTTPHeaders: {        server: "Server",        date: "Fri, 09 Aug 2019 20:57:23 GMT",        "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0",        "content-length": "385",        connection: "keep-alive",        "x-amzn-requestid":          "3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",        "x-amz-crc32": "1811639896"      },      RetryAttempts: 0    }  }};

const {
  job_type,
  job_status,
  job_data: { id }
} = data.responseBody.Item;
console.log(job_type, job_status, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a JSON object. It's a JavaScript object. Access the properties like normal:

```
const { id, job_type, job_status } = obj.Item.job_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have json file, you can use `JSON.parse()` and than use it as a object.

```js
let jsonData = '{"Item":{"job_change_request":"task0020764","id":"a156fc4e-e8d4-424f-a792-0c8cf8e3ca46","job_data":{"location":"sdqa03","id":"8f6087cb-b33d-41c4-9a71-e865fd444a1d","customer_id":"cust01291","change_request":"task0020764"},"job_requested_time":"2019-08-09T20:54:20.237536","job_type":"create_subnet","job_status":"completed"},"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","HTTPStatusCode":200,"HTTPHeaders":{"server":"Server","date":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 20:57:23 GMT","content-type":"application/x-amz-json-1.0","content-length":"385","connection":"keep-alive","x-amzn-requestid":"3TVF1M3UH7EIHUFJ0KA97F551NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","x-amz-crc32":"1811639896"},"RetryAttempts":0}}';

let obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(obj.Item.job_type);
console.log(obj.Item.job_status);
console.log(obj.Item.job_data);
```